# css overwrite with var() default to previous value

Tags: css, css-variables

Suppose I have the following style

```
.element {
   color : blue;
}
```

Now some other place I'd like to overwrite the element style with a css var but if the variable was not available I want to switch to the previous value without knowing what it was.

```
.element.overwrite {
    color: var(--foo); // but if --foo is undefined keep `blue`
    // color: var(--for, blue); // not this since I don't know what the previous value is. 
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you cannot do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare both `var` and your color in your main class and set your color variable in your subClass

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    background: var(--unknownColor, blue);
    color: var(--textColor, #000);
}

div.overwrite {
    --unknownColor: #E43030;
    --textColor: yellow;
}

div.overwriteSecond {
    --unknownColor: green;
    --textColor: purple;
}
```

```html
<div>aaaaa</div>
<div class="overwrite">aaaaa</div>
<div class="overwriteSecond">aaaaaa</div>
```

Comment: @Kosh `color: var(--var, black);` would still work.

Comment: @Yong, right...

Comment: Updated with `color`

Answer (score 0):

You might save your initial color into a var, then use that var in overwrite:

```css
b {
  color: var(--color);
}

.b1 {
  --color: blue;
}

.b2 {
  --color: green;
}

b.overwrite1 {
  --foo: red;
  color: var(--foo, var(--color));
}

b.overwrite2 {
  color: var(--bar, var(--color))
}
```

```html
<b class="b1">ELEMENT</b> | <b class="b1 overwrite1">VAR IS KNOWN</b> | <b class="b1 overwrite2">VAR IS UNKNOWN</b>

<hr>

<b class="b2">ELEMENT</b> | <b class="b2 overwrite1">VAR IS KNOWN</b> | <b class="b2 overwrite2">VAR IS UNKNOWN</b>
```